# How to chart custom DynaTrace measures and business transactions

Tags: dynatrace

I've been experimenting with custom measures and business transactions in DynaTrace 6.1 to retrieve information from a session. I am unable to added these new measures as a chart series.

The custom measure is a Web Request - Session Attribute Value and I've added it as a business transaction Split Results argument. Everything works great, but any time I attempt to add a series to a new or existing chart the only available business transactions are the 'Build-In' ones.

I've created other custom measures that are able to be added to charts, but business transactions appear to behave differently.

Does anyone know how to make a custom business transaction chart-able?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the dashboard you add the chart to has the Stored Session set as Data Source. Dashboards always have a primary data source - by default thats most likely your regular System Profile for monitoring your apps. If you want to chart data from a different source (different system profile or stored session) you need to change that source. You can do this via Dashboard -> Properties

Also - check out my video tutorials on [Dashboarding Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHmha3MtNYk&list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6&index=8) and [Advanced Dashboarding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRL5JrJB7KI&list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6&index=19)

If you have further questions also make sure you use our Dynatrace Discussion platform on http://answers.dynatrace.com

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think I'm using confusing terminology here. Basically, I'm using session attributes from an application session, not a Dynatrace stored session. I'm hoping to be able to chart the values of the session attributes over time. For example, when I open the business transaction and look at the table data, if I select a row (or multiple rows) I can right-click and select 'Show Measures in Chart', but the results charts are always empty. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Got it! You need to first capture that Session Attribute - you can do this via the Servlet or ASP.NET Sensor Properties. You can specify which Session ATtribute to capture. Now - the tricky thing is that by default you cant just chart these values as we capture them as string. What you can do is to create a Business Transaction that uses a Session Attribute Measure as Result Measure. Additonally you might want to define a filter so that the BT really only includes those PurePaths that have that Session Attribute set. If not clear - reach me as desribed here: http://bit.ly/sharepurepath

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the help Andreas, great explanation.